# ToupTek XCAM4K8MPA camera connection to Linux computer

Tags: camera, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to connect a **ToupTek XCAM4K8MPA** camera to a **Linux Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit** computer to use with their provided **ToupLite** software for microscopy image capturing. [The camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiKtK.png) comes with a USB 3.0 cable, HDMI cable and USB WLAN adapter.

I have managed to set up the ToupTek ToupLite software ([Link to manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1916151/Touptek-Hdmi-4k-Series.html?page=6#manual), [Link to download page](http://www.touptek.com/download/showdownload.php?lang=en&id=28)) which, as far as I understand, comes with the SDK included. I have then connected the camera via USB 3.0 and HDMI cable to the computer, but ToupLite shows *No device* as in, the camera is not recognized or connected. I have tested the camera by simply connecting it to a computer monitor via HDMI cable and it works, but for capture I would like it to be connected to a computer and the WLAN or Wi-Fi connection solution is not really a good option.

Perhaps someone has some ideas of what I am missing.

**Note:** Relevant tags include *touptek*, *touplite*, *microscopy*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the WLAN connection. Made a non-changing IP address for the camera and the ToupLite software recognizes that it is on the local network.

Additional info:
Tested it with Linux Ubuntu 22.04, when connected via USB3.0 connection, it can be seen the same as a web camera, using `cheese`.